# Webpack: can tree shaking be applied to preprocess dynamic imports?

Tags: webpack, dynamic-import

I'm looking at dynamic imports in webpack with the promise based:

`import('chunk').then(chunk => {...do something with chunk...})`.

Does webpack have anyway of eliminating dead code in this case? It seems that the entire esModule is imported by default without anyway of specifying what you need ahead of time.

**Update**

To clarify, when you only need function "f" from module "A.js", you could import it dynamically like this:

```
import('A.js').then(({f}) => {...})
```

this is the dynamic analogue of:

```
import {f} from 'A.js'
```

However, as far as I can tell, there is no way for webpack to optimize the bundle by pruning unneeded functions from 'A.js' in the dynamic version, I always get the entire module even if I only destructure and use one of many possible exports.

Is this just a limitation of webpack's dead code detection with dynamically loaded modules?

Comment: Do you mean dead code elimination inside the `chunk` module or removal of a conditional dynamic import as in this case: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6590

Comment: did you fix this dawg?